# Split A text-style cell to multiple cells by a fixed width

Tags: formatting

> Sample Cell 1

```
Cell["Much of point set topology consists in developing a convenient language to talk about when various points in a space are near to one another and about the notion of continuity. The key is that the same definitions can be applied to many disparate branches of math.", "Text"]
```

Split to multiple cells like

> Sample Cell 2

```
Cell["Much of point set topology consists in developing a convenient", "Text"]
Cell[" language to talk about when various points in a space are near", "Text"]
Cell[" to one another and about the notion of continuity. The key is", "Text"]
Cell[" that the same definitions can be applied to many disparate ", "Text"]
Cell["branches of math.", "Text"]
```

Though, in this example, they are all plaint text, maybe much simpler, the problem might be harder when there are many inline math cells.

---

Here is an sample post for why I need this, I wanna make first light-green block text into multiple framed lines like what below `Definition 4.1.1`.
http://quaternions.blog.163.com/blog/static/206082147201356102512774/

---

Bill's present method will not able to deal with the inline cells.

> Upadte 
>   sample Cell 3 with inline cells

```
Cell[TextData[{"Much of point set topology", Cell[BoxData[\(TraditionalForm\`\(\ consists\ \)\)], FormatType -> "TraditionalForm"], "in developing a convenient language to  talk about ", Cell[BoxData[\(TraditionalForm\`when\)], FormatType -> "TraditionalForm"], " various points in a space are near to one another and about the notion of ", Cell[BoxData[\(TraditionalForm\`\(continuity\^2\)\)], FormatType -> "TraditionalForm"], ". The key is that the same definitions can be applied to many disparate branches of math."}], "Text"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the first cell and give it a name:

```
myCell=Cell["Much of point set topology consists in developing a convenient language to  talk about when various points in a space are near to one another and about the notion of continuity. The key is that the same definitions can be applied to many disparate branches of math.", "Text"]
```

Here's a function to break it into pieces with about `n/2` words in each piece:

```
breakCell[str_, n_] := Cell /@ StringJoin /@ 
    Partition[Riffle[StringSplit[First[List @@ str]], " "], n]
```

For example, applying `breakCell` to `myCell` gives:

```
breakCell[myCell, 15]

{Cell["Much of point set topology consists in developing"], 
 Cell[" a convenient language to talk about when "], 
 Cell["various points in a space are near to"], 
 Cell[" one another and about the notion of "], 
 Cell["continuity. The key is that the same definitions"], 
 Cell[" can be applied to many disparate branches "]}
```

Comment: Hi, bill, there would be some problems when arbitrarily add some inline cells in myCell

Comment: Well... the code is right there -- I just took the `First` part. If there's more stuff, you will want to write something that handles that as well.

Comment: en, I should make my original cell just be cell with inline cells

Comment: How about select the part of the cell you want and then choose Cell->Divide Cells from the menu.

Comment: ha, that's too [adj...] for frequent work. Actually I get my Sample Cell2 from Sample Cell1 in that way.

Comment: bills, one similar question, welcome to be interested with that if had time.
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27114/split-one-string-about-a-fixed-width-with-syntaxq-true